# Wordpress gravity forms abn lookup

Tags: wordpress, forms, lookup, gravity

I'm having some trouble setting up a gravity form.

I am trying to create a form where a customer enters there abn which then gets checked through the abn lookup tool and then updates fields with the values returned e.g. Company Name, ABN status.

Could anyone tell me the best way to do this.

Cheers

Comment: i've been trying to create a filter in the functions.php file which submits the abn number and then returns the fields i want

Answer (score 2):

Jordon - I also needed to integrate the ABN Lookup in my Gravity Forms.

I ended up creating a plugin and have just released it on the WordPress plugins website.

If you still need to integrate the ABN Lookup in Gravity Forms check it out: [ABN Lookup for Gravity Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/abn-lookup-for-gravity-forms/)

Let me know how you go with it.